# Can StaxEventItemWriter be used to write complex XMLs?

Tags: spring-batch

I want to write an XML in below format:

```
<Parent>
<TotalEmployees>2</TotalEmployees>
<CompanyName>ABCD</CompanyName>
<Employee>
<Name>YYYYY</Name>
<Details>
<EmployeeId>12345</EmployeeId>
<Job>Permanent</Job>
</Details>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name>XXXXX</Name>
<Details>
<EmployeeId>67892</EmployeeId>
<Job>Contract</Job>
</Details>
</Employee>
</Parent>
```

The Employee fragement would repeat and the total number of employee statistics is provided in the TotalCount (calculated value).

Is this possible with StaxItemWriter or should I go for custom ItemWriter. I tried to use headercallback but it did not help. Please guide me.

Comment: To write the total number of records in the header, you need to calculate it upfront. Where are you reading items from? Can you calculate the total number of items upfront?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine : I am reading the records from the database, but i do filter some in the processor based on certain conditions.Is it possible to pass the total records count from processor to Writer?

Comment: Why don't you filter these records in the query itself? It's not efficient to grab records in the application's memory and filter them in a processor. If you manage to select only the items that should be written, you can create a step that does `select count(*) from table where ...`, and put that information in the execution context. Now your chunk oriented step can read the total number of items from the execution context and write it in the header.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine : Thanks for your detailed response. The problem is, I have to select from DB based on certain conditions and filter them by comparing the records I recieve from another input file (a CSV file) from an external system and then write to an XML. So i dont have the possibility to filter in the select query. Else i would have to first write from CSV to DB and then write what i fetch from new select query. But for this again i would have to create new table.

Comment: I see. In that case, you need to find a way to calculate the total number of items that will be written before writing the header.